# How to properly install latest Umlet java (globally)

Tags: linux, software-installation, .desktop

This is probably an easy question if someone has experience with this but I don't know what's the good practice.

- I've installed java with `sudo apt install default-jre`
- I have downloaded the latest Umlet 15 java program (UMLet 15.0 stand-alone) from the official site: https://www.umlet.com/changes.htm

After unzipping, I found .desktop file with this content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=UMLet
GenericName=UMLet
Comment=Free UML Tool for Fast UML Diagrams
Exec=java -Dsun.java2d.xrender=f -jar umlet.jar
Icon=img/umlet_logo.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

Notice that it's assuming the path of umlet.jar to be global (not doing ./umlet.jar) an also accessing `img/umlet_logo.png` locally.

How exactly is one supposed to use this file to be able to find the app in Applications and pin to taskbar?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is how it's supposed to be done because it feels wrong to have to change the provided .desktop file.

**Change paths to absolute**

`umlet.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=UMLet
GenericName=UMLet
Comment=Free UML Tool for Fast UML Diagrams
Exec=java -Dsun.java2d.xrender=f -jar /home/katzda/Programs/Umlet/umlet.jar
Icon=/home/katzda/Programs/Umlet/img/umlet_logo.png
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

I ran these commands:

```
cd Umlet
chmod 777 umlet.sh
cd ~
mkdir Programs
mv Umlet Programs/
sudo cp umlet.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

Although this approach feels wrong and ideally there should be an install script but it works.